# Fogbugz database schema management

Tags: database, schema, fogbugz-on-demand

This is a very simple question, and maybe the man himself can provide insight on this :)

Does anyone know the pseudocode behind how Fog Creek does database schema management?

I'm running into an issue and I'm trying to figure out if I'm handling it right... I have a module that runs each time someone spins up their site and examines their database to make sure that they have the right changes in place.  if they are missing changes, then the script makes the required changes.

My issue is that I was trying to tie it to the session_start portion of the Global.asax, but it seems to be rather flaky at times, and I'm trying to come up with a better scenario.

For reference, I'm trying to run 1 x web application that can respond to any number of hosts, where the host maps via a metabase to find out what database it belongs to and then makes the necessary connections.

Answer (score 1):

You might have more luck asking this on [http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest)

Comment: I thought about it... but thought that first it would have been worthwhile to talk to the stack overflow community first.

Comment: http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/questions/978/how-is-schema-managed-in-fogbugz-oe

In case anyone was interested, in the event I get an answer ;)